# Firebase: Couldn't find registrable Android clients in project

Tags: firebase, firebase-assistant

Firebase: Couldn't find registrable Android clients in project.
When i select release build type, android studio tell me "Firebase: Couldn't find registrable Android clients in project."
But debug type is ok.
[image]

Comment: Have you found the solution? If yes, please share as an answer.

Comment: For me, I just need to do the connection in DEBUG the first time to create the json file. The crashlytics will still work in RELEASE mode.

Answer (score 9):

Thanks to Angel Koh. This issue came when I kept the build variant as 'Release'.  I switched it to 'Debug' and was able to connect to Firebase with that.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try to download google-services.json from firebase project under firebase console and keep at app directory (app level).
If you have not created firebase project under firebase console, then go to firebase.google.com -> login -> go to console -> create new project (follow https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) -> download google-services.json -> save at app directory (app level)
you can follow android studio assistant firebase steps or https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup